# Disable object validation TS

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to disable the check for the presence of keys in an object and its nested objects so as not to get errors if they are not there, but at the same time leave hints for those that are? P.s I understand that in most cases this is not correct and not acceptable, but in my case there is no other way out, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: If you're leveraging interfaces you could always make the properties optional with a `?`...

Comment: An alternative to what @AlexanderNied said is to have an interface declared with all the required properties and then run `Partial<YourInterface>` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.